# how device back button is used in the fragments?

Tags: android-fragments

Please help me to give a code to go back to the previous fragments using device back button. Like the facebook app, when we press the device back button it will go to the home and again pressing device back button from the home, it will exit the app. I need a code for that. Please help me for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to **do your own management for this.** Detect back button pressed event and check which fragment is visible. **Hide/Visible fragments according your flow of code.**

I use this code for mantain by flow. This might help you.

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        MyLog.printLog("KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK");
        if (mCurScreen == R.id.screen_game) {
            View v = findViewById(R.id.iv_help_gameplay);
            if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                showExitAlert();
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```